# ngfor nested label id increment decrement according to items count

Tags: javascript, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular6, angular7

I have a label in which, it mentions the item added or removed by ngFor, I know I can put index but the index goes on without resetting.

Like

Member 1

Member 2 and so on.

But on adding and then removing and then adding again,

It becomes

Member 1

Member 3

I want that count to automatically become, Member 1 and Member 2

Please help, I’ve tried everything.

The add and remove buttons are placed outside of ngFor div, so that they don’t get replicated for every iteration.

```
   <div formArrayName="demoArray" 
  *ngFor="let arrayItem of arrayItems; let i=index">
     <div> Member {{  i+1 }} </div>
  <input [id]="arrayItem.id" type="checkbox"
     [formControl]="demoArray[i]">
  <label [for]="arrayItem.id" class="array-item-title">
     {{arrayItem.title}}</label>
```

Comment: Please add delete code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of assingning modified arrray of objects back to original array while deleting and push new object to original array on Add

**component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      name = 'Angular';
      arrayItems = [
        {id:1},
        {id:2},
        {id:3},
        ]
        delete(item){
          this.arrayItems = this.arrayItems.filter(v => v.id !== item.id)
        }
add(){
      this.id++;
      this.arrayItems.push({id: this.id})
    }
    }
```

Sample working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lszvvs?file=src/app/app.component.html

Updated stackblitz with same functionality but with using one Add and one Delete button as requested by SO - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fix4bj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi Naga Sai thanks for responding so soon. Is it possible to have the same functionality but with the add and delete buttons appearing only once with fixed position without repeating.

Comment: updated stackblitz- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fix4bj?file=src/app/app.component.ts with one button to check and uncheck multiple checkboxes to delete